# Docker error with read-only file system unknown

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using `Windows 10 x64` and just downloaded Docker, I tried running a simple "hello-world" dockerfile but I kept getting an error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: error creating temporary lease: file resize error: truncate /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown.`

Every time I try, I get the same file read-only error.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: windows 10 64 bit @Lukman

Comment: I only downloaded docker for windows and I dont know what to do from here, it seems like docker is running and I ran powershell as adminstrator and ran docker run hello-world but I keep getting that error

Comment: Do i have to run anything within the docker desktop app, I currently see no containers running

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run hello-world                              Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating temporary lease: file resize error: truncate /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started       Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating temporary lease: file resize error: truncate /var/lib/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db: read-only file system: unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Post the output of `docker info` and also check if your drive C: has enough free space (20+ GB). Docker is not complicated. Windows is complicating it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I remember correct after clearing space and Restarting Docker from scratch worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this has something to do with disk space (or lack thereof). Uninstall some stuff.

Answer (score 10):

On windows, open Docker desktop and click on the debug icon then restart. You can also consider "reset to factory defaults"
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was conflicting mounts in docker compose:

```yaml
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./services/nginx/static/:/var/www/:ro
      - ./services/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
```

chaged it to:

```yaml
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./services/nginx/static/:/var/www/PUBLIC:ro
      - ./services/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
```

Comment: no way to make it work with exactly the first configuration?

Answer (score 1):

My case the reason is a corrupted SSD. When you see the error, check `dmesg`. Mine is brutal:

```
[ 5395.061163] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 18906376 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5395.061166] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 2363041, async page read
[ 5395.061310] Aborting journal on device sdb2-8.
[ 5395.061315] EXT4-fs error (device sdb2) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:6000: Journal has aborted
[ 5395.065827] EXT4-fs error (device sdb2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[ 5395.065829] EXT4-fs (sdb2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 5395.067419] EXT4-fs error (device sdb2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[ 5395.067421] EXT4-fs error (device sdb2): mpage_map_and_submit_extent:2619: comm postgres: Failed to mark inode 2385447 dirty
[ 5395.067422] EXT4-fs (sdb2): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 9223372036854775803 pages, ino 14362621; err -30
[ 5395.202060] EXT4-fs error (device sdb2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Docker Desktop"-> "Settings"
Go to "Resources"->"File Sharing"
Add your project folder